# JavaScript Prototypal Inheritance Chain: "that" technique for accessing upper level properties and methods?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, super, chain, prototypal

I need to access properties and methods one level up in the prototype chain, when using prototypal inheritance.

Is this an acceptable technique?

```
function Cheese() {
    this.weight = 100;
    this.unit = 'g';
    this.that = this; // not sure about this... does it create a circular reference?
}

Cheese.prototype.setWeight = function(myWeight) {
    this.weight = myWeight;
}

var cheese = new Cheese();
var myCheddar = Object.create(cheese); // http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html
myCheddar.setWeight(500);

console.log(myCheddar.weight + myCheddar.unit); //-> 100kg
console.log(myCheddar.that.weight + myCheddar.unit); //-> 500g
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - there is no "inheritance" or extension set up in your code, so all properties are accessible on the main level. Are you maybe trying to access properties on the prototype instead of on the instance?

Comment: @jraede there is inheritance - see the `Object.create()` line ...

Comment: That's not inheritance, that's just creating a clone of the `cheese` variable if I read that article correctly. But most importantly, there is NO inheritance in javascript, aside from the fact that everything inherits from the `Object` prototype.

Comment: @jraede no, `Object.create()` makes a new object such that that new object has the passed-in object as its prototype.

Comment: Ok, so what, he wants to access a property on the prototype instead of the instance? That's still not inheritance.

Comment: @jraede yes I agree - well it kind-of is, because each instance created that way will see the property "that" via the prototype chain, and "that" will be a reference to the prototype object. I'm not sure what exactly the goal is however.

Comment: Right, but it's not like you can say `var prop = super.getProp()` or whatever like you can do in true classical languages. The maximum level of "inheritance" that you can differentiate is between the instance and the prototype.

Comment: There is inheritance in JavaScript; however it is not _classical_ (e.g., Java-style inheritance); it is _prototypal_. See link below. ~kjm~
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: Prototypal by default means there isn't inheritance. You have the prototype ("class") and the instance, but there is no inheritance chain unless you explicitly create one by merging objects and properties. Basically, if you want inheritance, you have to mimic it by extending an object with another object.

Comment: @jraede This thread is about determining whether or not the technique of using "this.that=this" in the constructor is an acceptable way to access the parent in the prototype chain. If you want to argue semantics about prototypal inheritance, first read _JavaScript, The Good Parts (Crockford)_, and then start your own thread.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

Object.getPrototypeOf;

Is the answer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf
http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/